# Draw ellipse form runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi

I tried to draw a ellipse form at runtime. I set the `TransparentKey` as same as `backColor` and the Form `borderStyle` to `none`. However it did not work form me. When i run the below code I am not getting the ellipse. I am not sure what missed over here.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Graphics graphicsObj = this.CreateGraphics();
    SolidBrush sBrush=new SolidBrush(Color.Orange);
    graphicsObj.FillEllipse(sBrush, 30, 30, 60, 30);
    sBrush.Dispose();
    graphicsObj.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: No `using`, drawing in c'tor.

Comment: @UweKeim Understood. But how to draw an ellipse in winform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drawing in WinForms doesn't work like this, at best you'll see it once but when the `Paint` event re-triggers it'll get removed.
What you can do is draw your ellipse in the `Paint` event:

```
private void OnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var g = e.Graphics;
    SolidBrush sBrush=new SolidBrush(Color.Orange);
    graphicsObj.FillEllipse(sBrush, 30, 30, 60, 30);
    sBrush.Dispose();
}
```

Edit:

You can find the OnPaint event on your Form (Events tab) or you could just subscribe to it from your constructor:
`this.Paint += OnPaint;`

Comment: where i could find this OnPaint event

Comment: I could not find OnPaint event in Form's Events tab. Achieved this by _overriding_ the event. Thanks for all your help.